# How to make my menu show only one div at a time?

Tags: jquery, html

This works fine, but when one div content is shown, if I click to show another div content, it overrides the first div. I want to show only one div at a time. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
  <div class="clicked">
    <p>Block 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="display:block;">
    <p>1Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
       Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
       Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clickable">
    <p>Block 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>2Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
       Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
       Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clickable">
    <p>Block 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>3Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
       Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
       Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.clicked, .clickable').on('click', function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('clickable')){
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('clicked');
      }
      else {
        $(this).next().hide();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked').addClass('clickable');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide all the `.content` divs on click before showing the one that was clicked on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clicked, .clickable').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('clickable')){
      $('.content').hide(); //Hide all content divs before showing the clicked one
      $(this).next().show();
      $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('clicked');
    } else {
      $(this).next().hide();
      $(this).removeClass('clicked').addClass('clickable');
    }
  });
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fuvvus7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/9owL9u37/

The CSS

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats very similar to a question that I submit earlier. Maybe this would help

http://codepen.io/mehmet/pen/BkJIu

jQuery

```
$('.trigger').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.show-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hidden', '');

  $('div[class*=show]').not($class).fadeOut().promise().done( function(){
    $('.show-' + $id).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display: none;}  
.trigger {display:block}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="trigger" id="content-1">link1</a>
<div class="show-content-1 hidden">Content 1</div>

<a href="#" class="trigger" id="content-2">link2</a>
<div class="show-content-2 hidden">Content 2</div>

<a href="#" class="trigger" id="content-3">link3</a>
<div class="show-content-3 hidden">Content 3</div>
<!-- remove hidden class from any div to display it when page loads -->
```