# How to make only one div have the class clicked at a time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This works very fine, but it accepts more than one div with the class 'clicked'. I just want one div on the page with the class 'clicked'. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="clicked">
  <p>Block 1</p>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display:block;">
  <p>1Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
  <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
   Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
   Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
  <p>Block 2</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>2Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
  <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
   Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
   Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
  <p>Block 3</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>3Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
  <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br/><br/>
   Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.
   Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.clicked, .clickable').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('clickable')){
      $('.content').hide();
      $(this).next().show();
      $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('clicked');
    }
    else {
      $(this).next().hide();
      $(this).removeClass('clicked').addClass('clickable');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')` - this will remove the class from the other divs. Call it before setting the class to the clicked div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go. You can simplify your code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.clicked, .clickable').on('click', function () {
        // Remove clicked class from every element.
        $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');

        // Hide every element with class content
        $('.content').hide();

        // Toggle between the two available classes, and on the same
        // go show the sibling element with class content.
        $(this).toggleClass('clickable clicked').next('.content').show();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/qqpf492o/)

Answer (score 4):

In your click handler:

```
$('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
$(this).addClass('clicked');
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems all you need to do is remove "clicked" from everything.  Just add one line like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.clicked, .clickable').on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('clickable')){
            $('.content').hide();
            $(this).next().show();
            $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // ADD THIS LINE
            $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('clicked');
        } else {
            $(this).next().hide();
            $(this).removeClass('clicked').addClass('clickable');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this question to you like 3 hours ago :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239480/3637090

http://jsfiddle.net/9owL9u37/

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).next().show();
       $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, but I want to load my page with the first div with "clicked" class and it seems is not working.. your code is  not changing the classes of the clickable/clicked div element...