# On Off Button Toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mobile toolbar that has four buttons.  Each button is using a sprite to position a background image. Each button has a unique class name as each needs to be positioned uniquely within the sprite.

When the page loads, no buttons are selected.  When a button is pressed, it's active psuedo class :active changes from a white icon to a blue icon, when the button is released from it's active state in blue, it stays blue.  No problem.  But then the behavior I want is when another button is pressed, that button change it's state to the active state and the button that was in active state before this one, returns to its default state.

So when a button is pressed, it's state persists in active, and goes back to its default state when another button is pressed.

Here is the HTML of the buttons:

```
<div id="s800-footer" align="center" class="s800-toolbar">
        <button id="s800-current-location-btn" class="locationIcon" ></button>
        <button id="s800-1-map-btn" class="s800-footer-btn mapIcon" >Map</button>
        <button id="s800-2-facility-list-btn" class="s800-footer-btn listIcon" >List</button>
        <button id="s800-3-choose-btn" class="s800-clickable s800-footer-btn chooseIcon">Choose</button>
        <button id="s800-4-selected-options-btn" class="s800-footer-btn selectedIcon">Selected</button>
    </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
 $(".s800-toolbar button").click(function(){        
    if ($(this).hasClass("mapIcon")){
         $(this).removeClass("mapIcon");
         $(this).addClass("active");

        $(".listIcon").removeClass("listIconActive");
        $(".listIcon").addClass("listIcon");        

    }else if ($(this).hasClass("listIcon")){
        $(this).removeClass("listIcon");
        $(this).addClass("listIconActive");
        $(".mapIcon").removeClass("mapIconActive");
        $(".mapIcon").addClass("mapIcon");   
    }

    })
```

From left to right on the toolbar the icons are the .mapIcon, the .listIcon, the .chooseIcon, and the .selectedIcon.  I've only included code for the first two because once I get  the .mapIcon to turn off it's active state when the .listIcon is pressed, I can replicate the functionality to the others.

Thanks in advance. 
Chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make only one div have the class clicked at a time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242619/how-to-make-only-one-div-have-the-class-clicked-at-a-time). And you can find many more just by searching.

Comment: can you add a working JSFiddle demo please ? Did you tried to play with radio button, where only one button can be selected at any given time ?

Comment: Think about it. If you remove the class `mapIcon`, there will be no way for you to reselect it later...Simplify the CSS.

Comment: I'm totally getting confused. why do you have `active`, `listIconActive`,  `mapIconActive` etc? why not single `active` class? why are you removing their original classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating it. First `:active` is not the same thing as a class `.active`. Second, simplify the JavaScript so it is not a bunch of hardcoded checks. That leads to too much maintenance, keep it simple.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <button class="icon1">A</button>
    <button class="icon2">B</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon1 { 
    background-color: #CCCC00;
}
.icon1.selected { 
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
.icon2 { 
    background-color: #00CCCC;
}
.icon2.selected { 
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".toolbar").on("click", "button", function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("selected")  //If you do not want people to remove the selection, then do not call toggleClass
          .siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uag99r6/

Comment: Interesting response this is Epascarello.  I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: When you first load the page, what if I wanted .icon1's default state to be "selected"?

I'd appreciate it.

Comment: So why don't you have it set to start in the HTML? Other choice would be to call "click" on it. `$(".icon1").click();`

Answer (score 0):

The answer I would like to give is to make the class names uniform, and use `removeClass` toward all the buttons before setting one of them active.

Here's an idea:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" class="btn" ></button>
    <button id="button2" class="btn" ></button>
    <button id="button3" class="btn" ></button>
    <button id="button4" class="btn" ></button>
    <button id="button5" class="btn" ></button>
</div>

.btn{
    background-image:(....);
    background-position: ....;
}
#button1&.active{  //Active button styles
    background-image:(....);
    background-position: ....;
}


$("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".btn").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three classes for each button.
For the map icon, there is:

.mapIcon, 
.mapIcon:active, 
.active

.listIcon, 
.listIcon:active, 
.listIcon.active

Same for the other two.  And I cannot just give them all the same class such as '.btn', and then set a background image and position for that because I'm using a sprite sheet, and each image is positioned according to different coordinates on the sprite sheet. Here is the full CSS if you care to see:

```
.mapIcon{
     background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat -267px -84px;
    width:42px;
     border:0;
     text-align: center;
 }
.mapIcon:active{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -332px -84px !important;
    }
.active{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -332px -84px !important;
 }
.listIcon{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: -413px -82px !important;
    width:42px;
    border:0;

}
.listIcon:active{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 6px -127px !important;
    width:42px;
    border:0;
}
.listIconActive{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 3px -127px !important;
   width:42px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.chooseIcon{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: -56px -127px !important;
    /*height:45px;*/
    width:53px;
    border:0;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.chooseIcon:active{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: -480px 0px !important;
   width:57px;
    border:0;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.chooseIconActive{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: -480px 0px !important;
   width:57px;
    border:0;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.selectedIcon{
    background:url(../images/sprite_sheet.png) no-repeat !important ;
    background-position: -150px -127px !important;
    width:60px;
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
  }

 .selectedIcon:active{
    background:url(../images/locator_glyphs_copy.png) no-repeat !important ;
    background-position: -616px 0px !important;
    width:60px;
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
  }

 .selectedIconActive{
    background:url(../images/locator_glyphs_copy.png) no-repeat !important ;
    background-position: -616px 0px !important;
    width:60px;
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
   }
```